# Turn off autoComplete in Combobox in wpf

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, combobox

I am using .NET framework 4.0 to build my application.

I have a combobox in which I want to turn off suggest-append mode of combobox. Instead I want suggest-only mode.

In many questions users ask for turning autoComplete feature off and everywhere I got the same answer. i.e. set IsTextSearchEnabled to False.

When IsTextSearchEnabled = True

[image]

When IsTextSearchEnabled = False

[image]

What I want is :

[image]

When User Presses Enter on the Combobox I want the Item to be appended to the textbox of the combobox.

Is this thing possible in WPF?

Comment: It is possible. Listen to TextChanged of the TextBox and whenever the Text is not equal the text you entered simply replace it with the one you entered. That is how you will keep only your text in TextBox. Though when enter pressed then take SelectedItem and place it in TextBox.

Comment: What do you mean by  Listen to TextChanged of the TextBox and whenever the Text is not equal the text you entered simply replace it with the one you entered ? Can you give me a demo example?

Comment: Yea I will give you a demo. I mean it is the TextBox that you type in. When you look at ControlTemplate of ComboBox you will figure out the part name of the TextBox. Then you can literally get the instance of the TextBox and listen to TextChanged event. When you start typing the ComboBox will search for best match and it will replace your entered Text with the Text of best match. To avoid that simply always push your text to be the current Text of the TextBox. That is what I ment. I will post you a demo in a answer.

Comment: I did not find any TextChanged Event On ComboBox.

Comment: I found the TextChangedEvent on ComboBox. It is `TextBoxBase.TextChanged = "YourEventHandler"`. But I don't know the implementation.

Comment: I posted you an example. Check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like promised here is the demo. As you can see I did what I explained in my comments. I listened to text changed event.

Check it out:

```
<Grid>
    <local:MyComboBox x:Name="comboBox" IsEditable="True"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              IsTextSearchEnabled="True">
        <ComboBoxItem>hello</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>world</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>123</ComboBoxItem>
    </local:MyComboBox>
</Grid>

public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    private string myValue;
    private bool needsUpdate;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        TextBox tbx = this.GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox") as TextBox;

        tbx.PreviewKeyDown += (o, e) =>
        {
            this.needsUpdate = true;
        };

        tbx.TextChanged += (o, e) =>
            {
                if (needsUpdate)
                {
                    myValue = tbx.Text;
                    this.needsUpdate = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    tbx.Text = myValue;
                }
            };

        base.OnApplyTemplate();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry to say but I don't see any change in the output. My Output looks same as the first image in the question.

Comment: I noticed a change that when I press up or down arrow keys the text of the textbox changes for first time the arrow key is pressed but after that no matter how many times i press the arrow keys the text in the textbox does not change but the selection of the item changes by pressing up or down arrow key.

Comment: It works for me. When I open the ComboBox and start typing the autocomplite feature is being turned off. What are you doing exactly with the ComboBox?

Comment: My fault. I have tried to do it in the TextBoxBase.PreviwKeyDown and TextBoxBase.TextChanged. Now got it to work but another problem arises. Now all the resources whose TargetType is ComboBox does not apply to this one. And every thing is just not working as before.

Comment: Hi, glad it works for you now. If I was able to help you out with autocomplete issue feel free to mark this as answer or vote it up. Second, yes, I didnt know you have styles defined though you will have to change targettype and all will work again.