# Editable ComboBox without Text Search

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, textbox

I have an editable combobox:

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True" IsTextSearchEnabled="False"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Wheat"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
    <ComboBox.Items> 
        <ComboBoxItem Content="a"/> 
        <ComboBoxItem Content="f"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="v"/>
    </ComboBox.Items>
</ComboBox>
```

I can select things from the list and I can write custom text (for example 'R').

When I put false in IsTextSearchEnabled the selected index does not work properly.

i.e. when I write a value that is not in the list, the selected index **does not change to -1.**

Also, when I write a value in the list, the correct index is not selected, but remains in the previous index.

On the other hand, I'm not interested in TextSearch's behavior.

How can I disable the TextSearch behavior without affecting the behavior of the selected index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turn off autoComplete in Combobox in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20291213/turn-off-autocomplete-in-combobox-in-wpf)

Comment: This is the expected behaviour and the way the built-in ComboBox works. No new item is selected if there is no match and this also means that the SelectedIndex is not reset to -1. Your definition of "work properly" is apparently different from the control creators's definition.